# JDK 10 installation on windows 10 - is it possible?

Tags: installation, windows-10, java-10

When I am running freshly downloaded `jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe`, no frame for JDK setup appears, but after some waiting, I have to confirm I really want to install, again some waiting... And nothing. Checksums are checked, the file is downloaded correctly.

Windows logs are empty, except Security folder - there appears info about the installation confirmed by admin. ("*Special privileges assigned to new logon*")

When I am trying to install Java 10 in safe mode, installation is refused with message: "*Unable to install Java-- There are errors in the following switches:* " - and path/name of an existing word file from my comp is added.

If I am installing `jdk-8u171-windows-x64.exe`, it behaves correctly - the frame for JDK setup appears.

I took the last jdk9 installation and it worked OK. On the contrary, the previous version of jdk10 has the same problems.

After windows update from 12 June 2018, the jdk still won't install, but the Event Viewer started to show information, attached at the end.

jre10, fails too, but gives one more line of info:
Event 916

```
DllHost (17908,G,0) The beta feature EseDiskFlushConsistency is enabled in ESENT due to the beta site mode settings 0x800000.
```

The jdk10. when installing, is not only incapable of starting the Windows Installer service, but changes it into some unusable state, unable to be either started or stopped or to change the startup type. All actions are disabled. IMHO, it is creating some errors in registry. No java can be installed after that. I use Auslogic Registry Cleaner for removing all errors, and it sees errors in Missing Software and File Extensions. After cleaning, again `jdk`'s up to version 9 can be installed, but jdk10 cannot.

---

### Addendum: win logs from event viewer

**Error: Event 1000, Application error:**
General:

```
Faulting application name: jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe, version: 10.0.1.0, time stamp: 0x5ab9acf7
Faulting module name: jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe, version: 10.0.1.0, time stamp: 0x5ab9acf7
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000038686
Faulting process id: 0x410c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d402dfd1d06b4f
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Pet\AppData\Local\Temp\jds45540468.tmp\jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Users\Pet\AppData\Local\Temp\jds45540468.tmp\jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
Report Id: 9aadc165-69ba-47ca-83cb-7e544b97d566
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

**Information: Event 1001, Windows error reporting**
General:

```
Fault bucket 1992655966258265519, type 4
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
P2: 10.0.1.0
P3: 5ab9acf7
P4: jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
P5: 10.0.1.0
P6: 5ab9acf7
P7: c0000005
P8: 0000000000038686
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER1875.tmp.mdmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER19BF.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER19BD.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WER1A4B.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_jdk-10.0.1_windo_3196e2cb1dd2a8705411f17a55548c92911fba_2e00ac47_43b71fa9

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 9aadc165-69ba-47ca-83cb-7e544b97d566
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: a77a474917c24117dba7560b3462fdaf
```

The ReportArchive file, containing all that info, is here:

```
  Version=1
  EventType=APPCRASH
  EventTime=131733449510187922
  ReportType=2
  Consent=1
  UploadTime=131733449515828235
  ReportStatus=268435456
  ReportIdentifier=81bdd029-075c-450b-b682-c3fadd0ba6cc
  IntegratorReportIdentifier=9aadc165-69ba-47ca-83cb-7e544b97d566
  Wow64Host=34404
  NsAppName=jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
  AppSessionGuid=0000410c-0001-001b-4f6b-d0d1df02d401
  TargetAppId=W:000681d6e081fa534f85933d7e8e3ba49a5600000904!00000308d0d6c4263074d947aab23f0ab4555c1038c6!jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
  TargetAppVer=2018//03//27:02:31:19!185e25c1!jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
  BootId=4294967295
  TargetAsId=1340
  Response.BucketId=a77a474917c24117dba7560b3462fdaf
  Response.BucketTable=4
  Response.LegacyBucketId=1992655966258265519
  Response.type=4
  Sig[0].Name=Application Name
  Sig[0].Value=jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
  Sig[1].Name=Application Version
  Sig[1].Value=10.0.1.0
  Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
  Sig[2].Value=5ab9acf7
  Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
  Sig[3].Value=jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
  Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
  Sig[4].Value=10.0.1.0
  Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
  Sig[5].Value=5ab9acf7
  Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
  Sig[6].Value=c0000005
  Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
  Sig[7].Value=0000000000038686
  DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
  DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.16299.2.0.0.256.48
  DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
  DynamicSig[2].Value=1029
  DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
  DynamicSig[22].Value=4879
  DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
  DynamicSig[23].Value=4879b17999deda1d1b9f0343bdb031ad
  DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
  DynamicSig[24].Value=fa2f
  DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
  DynamicSig[25].Value=fa2f0ab4c038d1015efa9327567aae21
  UI[2]=C:\Users\Pet\AppData\Local\Temp\jds45540468.tmp\jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
  UI[3]=Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working
  UI[4]=Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
  UI[5]=Check online for a solution and close the program
  UI[6]=Check online for a solution later and close the program
  UI[7]=Close the program
  LoadedModule[0]=C:\Users\Pet\AppData\Local\Temp\jds45540468.tmp\jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
  LoadedModule[1]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
  LoadedModule[2]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
  LoadedModule[3]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
  LoadedModule[4]=C:\Program Files\Bitdefender\Bitdefender Security\atcuf\263415673164566198\atcuf64.dll
  LoadedModule[5]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
  LoadedModule[6]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
  LoadedModule[7]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
  LoadedModule[8]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
  LoadedModule[9]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
  LoadedModule[10]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
  LoadedModule[11]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
  LoadedModule[12]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
  LoadedModule[13]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
  LoadedModule[14]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
  LoadedModule[15]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
  LoadedModule[16]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
  LoadedModule[17]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
  LoadedModule[18]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
  LoadedModule[19]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
  LoadedModule[20]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
  LoadedModule[21]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
  LoadedModule[22]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\advapi32.dll
  LoadedModule[23]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
  LoadedModule[24]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
  LoadedModule[25]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
  LoadedModule[26]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
  LoadedModule[27]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
  LoadedModule[28]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msi.dll
  LoadedModule[29]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
  LoadedModule[30]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
  LoadedModule[31]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
  LoadedModule[32]=C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.16299.492_none_15c8d3609364b9b0\Comctl32.dll
  LoadedModule[33]=C:\WINDOWS\System32\coml2.dll
  State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
  State[0].Value=1
  OsInfo[0].Key=vermaj
  OsInfo[0].Value=10
  OsInfo[1].Key=vermin
  OsInfo[1].Value=0
  OsInfo[2].Key=verbld
  OsInfo[2].Value=16299
  OsInfo[3].Key=ubr
  OsInfo[3].Value=492
  OsInfo[4].Key=versp
  OsInfo[4].Value=0
  OsInfo[5].Key=arch
  OsInfo[5].Value=9
  OsInfo[6].Key=lcid
  OsInfo[6].Value=1049
  OsInfo[7].Key=geoid
  OsInfo[7].Value=75
  OsInfo[8].Key=sku
  OsInfo[8].Value=48
  OsInfo[9].Key=domain
  OsInfo[9].Value=0
  OsInfo[10].Key=prodsuite
  OsInfo[10].Value=256
  OsInfo[11].Key=ntprodtype
  OsInfo[11].Value=1
  OsInfo[12].Key=platid
  OsInfo[12].Value=10
  OsInfo[13].Key=sr
  OsInfo[13].Value=0
  OsInfo[14].Key=tmsi
  OsInfo[14].Value=207972
  OsInfo[15].Key=osinsty
  OsInfo[15].Value=3
  OsInfo[16].Key=iever
  OsInfo[16].Value=11.492.16299.0-11.0.70
  OsInfo[17].Key=portos
  OsInfo[17].Value=0
  OsInfo[18].Key=ram
  OsInfo[18].Value=8120
  OsInfo[19].Key=svolsz
  OsInfo[19].Value=222
  OsInfo[20].Key=wimbt
  OsInfo[20].Value=0
  OsInfo[21].Key=blddt
  OsInfo[21].Value=180502
  OsInfo[22].Key=bldtm
  OsInfo[22].Value=1908
  OsInfo[23].Key=bldbrch
  OsInfo[23].Value=rs3_release_svc_escrow
  OsInfo[24].Key=bldchk
  OsInfo[24].Value=0
  OsInfo[25].Key=wpvermaj
  OsInfo[25].Value=0
  OsInfo[26].Key=wpvermin
  OsInfo[26].Value=0
  OsInfo[27].Key=wpbuildmaj
  OsInfo[27].Value=0
  OsInfo[28].Key=wpbuildmin
  OsInfo[28].Value=0
  OsInfo[29].Key=osver
  OsInfo[29].Value=10.0.16299.492.amd64fre.rs3_release_svc_escrow.180502-1908
  OsInfo[30].Key=buildflightid
  OsInfo[30].Value=FE2BA97F-43C5-48BE-97E6-ACB9DE47C182.1
  OsInfo[31].Key=edition
  OsInfo[31].Value=Professional
  OsInfo[32].Key=ring
  OsInfo[32].Value=Retail
  OsInfo[33].Key=containerid
  OsInfo[34].Key=containertype
  OsInfo[35].Key=edu
  OsInfo[35].Value=0
  FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
  ConsentKey=APPCRASH
  AppName=Java(TM) Platform SE binary
  AppPath=C:\Users\Pet\AppData\Local\Temp\jds45540468.tmp\jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe
  NsPartner=windows
  NsGroup=windows8
  ApplicationIdentity=1121E2054339566427FD08593249BC16
  MetadataHash=1189992581
```

Comment: I'm using the windows 10 AND jdk 10 (x64). I've installed the jdk from official Oracle site. Are there some additional informations you can provide about your problem? Just for info - my computer is 12 years old...

Comment: Have you seen something special during installation? I am afraid, I have written here all info I noticed. My comp is 4-5 years old, but that does not matter really, maybe only the memory... But I have enough.

Comment: I didn't see anything different during the installations of JDK-10, JDK-9, and JDK 8_151. Also, I am certain the memory isn't the source of your problem. Have you checked the MD5? Maybe your downloaded file is somehow corrupted?

Comment: @zlakad Checksums are checked - they are OK.

Comment: I'm sure that I've never experienced any difficulties when I ran *any* Oracle Java installer (and I always used .exe files). What comes to my mind is to see the events in the Event Viewer. Maybe, check the antivirus program. Or, try to install java in different folder *from* different location? I'm almost sure there is some problem with the Windows OS. Read/write permissions? What else? I really don't know. I'm sorry I couldn't help you... Good luck, friend. I'm sure you'll find the way.

Comment: @zlakad I had not too - in the past, half a year ago the last time. But I am having the actual win 10 now. Do you, too? Have you tried it now? I think,too, that it is the miracle of MS (mentioned in the QA). But what have I to do? Events Viewer says nothing - I am citing it in the question.

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, Version 1803, OS Build 17134.48 ---- java 10 2018-03-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)

Comment: @zlakad And you have tried installation of jdk10 on it? Mine is Version 1709, build 16299.461. And it claims it is actual.

Comment: I've updated JDK-10 right now. It took me awhile since my comp is really slow. Update was successful: java 10.0.1 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)

Comment: @zlakad So, I have some defective windows.... Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Try to update it manually - what else?

Comment: @zlakad MS provided a new update an hour ago. Trying now.

Comment: @zlakad didn't help...

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot imagine why... There is one more possibility, but it's painful like hell - I wouldn't do it. It's windows fresh start (in the settings). I've never used it before, so I don't know what data and apps will be destroyed. There is nothing else I can say (except thank you for up voting my old answers - you didn't have to do it, I don't care so much for reputation). I really hope that you will find the solution for your problem. Cheers, friend

Comment: @zlakad you were installing not jdk10, but jre10.

Comment: No, I installed JDK 10, and within that the proper JRE will be installed. I don't really know is there a log file associated with Java installer. In your shoes, I would remove all the previous Java installations and go from stretch. Also, I'd check registry with regedt

Comment: I barely look at your edit - *AppPath=C:\Users\Pet\AppData\Local\Temp\jds45540468.tmp\jdk-10.0.1_windows-x64_bin.exe*. **Temp** is somewhat that's worrying me

Comment: 1. As I see it, the jdk10 breaks some registers. Older jdk's work OK. 2. I have edited the question according to the last attempts. 3. Sorry, in your comment you mentioned only Runtime Environment and Java HotSpot. As for the last, I am not installing it.

Comment: Java HotSpot was installed automatically!

Comment: Maybe, I have not noticed, sorry. Anyway, for me for jdk10 the process never arrives at the point where it shows what components will be installed.

Comment: I hate this warnings about *discussion to chat*, but if you are willing I am available in next 10-15 minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173229/discussion-between-zlakad-and-gangnus).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? If not JDK 10.0.2 was released on July 17 - maybe that is worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and have solved it in rather funny way.

Just simply extract and copy the extraction result to the folder which the Java SDK should be reside.

Simply right click the exe file and select extract (btw.. I am using 7zip).
It will extracted to a folder which contain one zip file (named tools.zip).

Extract that tools.zip, you will get all file of JDK 10.0.2
Then just copy it to your intended folder..

Comment: Welcome to SO. And thank you. I will check your way later. Please add the following info to the answer:  Why had you tried that handmade installation? The automatic one didn't work?

Comment: Yeah, the automatic one didn't work in one of our PC.
The other PCs and laptop is just fine. 

I have removed all existing Java.. But still cannot install Java JDK 10.0.2
I will try to install again if the next JDK version is exist